# Run multiple functions parallel in php

Tags: php, mysql, pcntl

I want to run 5 functions in parallel and all these functions will return result from SQL.

I planned to use `pcntl_fork();` but didn't knew how to assign values to those variables.

Comment: Please share the code you've tried so far, along with a specific question

Comment: I was getting data from query, and single query take 10 second and queries are running one after the other, i want a process where all these queries run parallely and return me the result and assign to respective keys.`$result = array();
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    $result[$value] = $this->getDetailData( $value );
}`

Comment: I have gone through that doc as well, but how i assign the values assigned to it...